# AJAX to call a partial view

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My legacy project in Web Forms would show a panel when the user clicks on a button.  My current project is to rebuild this functionality in C# MVC.

This view  will use Javascript and AJAX to show a partial view on demand.  The code flows properly in the debugger, but does not call the partial view.

I have used SOF posts to set up the JS so that the div containing the partial view is properly shown.  What am I missing in the AJAX or elsewhere?  (Maybe I need to decorate the target action?  Maybe I need to do something in the partial view?)

The relevant portion of the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//Show the Add Project section.
function NewProject() {
    //1. Reset the Add Project partial view.
    //2. Show the Add Project partial view.
    //3. Put focus into the project title field.
    //4. Hide the button.
    $("#divNewProject").show();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Organization/AddProject/"
    }).done(function () {
        $("#divNewProject").html(data);
        $("#ProjectTitle").focus();
        $("#ProjectTitle").scrollIntoView();
    });
    $("#divAddProject").hide();
}
</script>
```

...

```
<div id="divAddProject">
    @* Button to add a project, showing/hiding a partial view *@
    <button type="button" name="btnAddProject" id="btnAddProject" value="Add" onclick="NewProject()" class="btn">
        <span class="wizard-step-text">Add New Project</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div id="divNewProject" hidden="hidden">
    This is a test. It should start out hidden and later be shown.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
function NewProject() {

$("#divNewProject").show();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddProject","Organization")',
        success : function(data)
        {

        $("#divNewProject").html(data);
        $("#ProjectTitle").focus();
        $("#ProjectTitle").scrollIntoView();
        $("#divAddProject").hide();

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Does putting the code in the success section make sure that the code executes only if the action completes?

Comment: the OP is appending response data and it will be available in sucess clalback function

Comment: I moved the lines `$("#divNewProject").show();` and `$("#divAddProject").hide();` inside the success callback.  TXVM.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer yes it makes sure that the code will only execute when ajax call completes successfully if any error occurs on server side it will call error call back function that i have not added you can add that as well, ``error:function(){ }``

Comment: Good idea.  I added a placeholder for `error: function` for future implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The function inside done should have "data" as parameter.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Organization/AddProject/"
}).done(function (data) {
    $("#divNewProject").html(data);
    $("#ProjectTitle").focus();
    $("#ProjectTitle").scrollIntoView();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you debug, set a breakpoint inside the `done` function. It should hit, and you'll see that you haven't defined the `data` variable.

It should be:

```
}).done(function(data) {
    // Do something with data
})
```